# How to disable mach_msg_trap breakpoint xcode 8.3?

Tags: ios, dart, flutter, xcode8

When I run my Flutter Dart app from XCode on a connected iPhone, XCode breaks multiple times on any user interaction on SIGPIPE in "libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap".

Neither the breakpoint navigator in XCode nor `breakpoint list` in `lldb` show any breakpoints, so I cannot disable this.

How can I either disable this strange breakpoint or workaround the issue by telling XCode to always continue execution when it happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this has been [fixed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10358) on master. Try upgrading.

Or you can add this to your app delegate:

```
 signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: Upgrading solved the issue, as suggested. Thanks. Apparently, I should upgrade more often than once per week - this is really bleeding edge.